# How to use items in Dragonball Z Xenoverse?

Tags: dragon-ball-xenoverse

I keep acquiring new items in Dragonball Xenoverse, but how do I use them? How can I view my inventory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go to the menu(on xbox 360 controller the start button) then there is an option called inventory